# optimize wordpress site sharing with bluehost

Tags: wordpress, optimization, vps, bluehost

my site takes so time to load how can I fix this problem, I have a wp site it's shared with Bluehost when I run the site take so time to load any idea how to solve this issue?!

Comment: I guess there are many factors that could influence the time your wp takes to load. For example the plugins you use. Checkout this site, and similar ones: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/

Answer (score 0):

A lot of factors are involved in website speed, use some tool to scan your site and have some information:

**Google PageSpeed** help you to understand if image are too big, if the server response time id too high etc.. and also give you some information about the possible fix.
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=IT

Other thing that may help you to speed up your site is a cache plugin like:

- w3 total cache
- wp super cache
- ...

this plugin have a default settings that help also unexperienced user to have a little benefit.